# What's the best way to check if a user has flattr a thing the last month?

Tags: api, flattr

I had a little database fu*k-up and now I have to check If a User has flattred something in the last month to not double flattr these things. What's the best way to do it with the API? Is there anything more elegant then simply getting the list of the authenticated users flattrs and then check if the given thing is in that list?

Thanks :)

Comment: You know you can't double flattr a thing in our system? If you try to flattr a thing that the current user already flattred you get a error from our API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the users flattrs to look for a date and the ID of the thing to find out if a user has flattrd a thing last month.

If you want to know if the user has flattred a thing in the current period there is a parameter called `flattred` with is a boolean.